# Select faces depending on material

Tags: python, materials, vertices

I try to remove all the faces of different objects that have a certain material assigned to its face. But I can't get the select part to work.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

scene = bpy.context.scene

mat1 = bpy.data.materials['c1'] #This is the material name that I want

for ob in scene.objects: #For all objects
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        for mat in ob.material_slots:
            if mat.material == mat1:
             bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle() 

             mat.material.material_slot_select() # This doesnt work and i dont know if the later code work aswell
             me = ob.data


             bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
             faces_select = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select] 

             bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=faces_select, context=5)  

             bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
else: 
    ob.select = False
```

What is wrong, what shall I write?

Br

Comment: You can select faces based on material with `Shift G` > *Material* in edit mode..

Answer (score 6):

```
import bpy
import bmesh

mat_c1 = bpy.data.materials['c1']

for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        # get all the slot indexes to which mat_c1 is assigned
        c1_slots = [id for id, mat in enumerate(ob.data.materials) if mat == mat_c1]

        # you can also change active_material with
        # ob.active_material_index = some_number
        # and then run operators to deselect all faces and select material with
        # bpy.ops.material_slot_select()
        # but operators are bad so we will do it differently

        faces_mat_c1 = []
        bm = bmesh.new()
        bm.from_mesh(ob.data)
        # no need to swith into edit mode

        for face in bm.faces:
            if face.material_index in c1_slots:
                # face has mat_c1 assigned
                faces_mat_c1.append(face)

        # delete faces with mat_c1
        bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=faces_mat_c1, context=5)
        bm.to_mesh(ob.data)
        bm.free()
    else: 
        ob.select = False
```

Comment: thank you for a really helpful answer! It worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad it helped, you can mark it as correct for others to know, thx.)

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny I want to go over all materials and select (or get indices of) faces to which that specific material has been applied to, without using `bmesh` (if possible). I haven't been able to find a good solution for doing that as of now. I would appreciate if you can take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103307/how-to-get-indices-of-the-faces-to-which-a-material-has-been-applied-to-using-p) and see if you can offer a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question and answer.
If you are changing a single object, this code should help.

This code is a script that changes the size of the UV layer of the selected active material's UV.

**For Blender 3.2**

```
import bpy
import bmesh


factor = 1.01
# Get the active material for the object
obj = bpy.context.active_object
mat = obj.active_material

savemode = str(bpy.context.mode)
if savemode == "EDIT_MESH":
    savemode = "EDIT"

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

obj = bpy.context.active_object
mat_c1 = mat
c1_slots = [id for id, mat in enumerate(obj.data.materials) if mat == mat_c1]

me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()
# currently blender needs both layers.
bm.faces.layers.face_map.verify() 

# scale UVs xfactor
for f in bm.faces:
    if f.material_index in c1_slots:
        for l in f.loops:
            l[uv_layer].uv *= factor


bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=savemode)
```